# Python Pandas - Carrying the index over as the group name/index for a groupby produced dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have used groupby in pandas, however the label for the groups is simply an arbitrary value, whereas I would like this label to be the index of the original dataframe (which is datetime) so that I can create a new dataframe which I can plot in terms of datetime.

```
    grouped_data = df.groupby(
            ['X',df.X.ne(df.X.shift()).cumsum().rename('grp')])

    grouped_data2 = grouped_data['Y'].agg(np.trapz).loc[2.0:4.0]
```

The column x has changing values from 1-4 and the second line of code is intended to integrate the column Y in the groups where X is either 2 or 3. These are repeating units, so I don't want all the 2s and all the 3s integrated together, I want the period of time where it goes: `22222333333` as one group and then apply the np.trapz again to the next group where it goes: `2222233333`. That way I should have a new dataframe with an index corresponding to the start of these time periods and values which are an integral of these periods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've already set your index to DateTime values? If yes, try the grouper function:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key={index name}, freq={appropriate offset alias}))
```

Without a sample data-set, I can't really provide a complete solution, but this should solve your indexing issue:)

[Grouper Function tutorial](http://pbpython.com/pandas-grouper-agg.html)

[Offset aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)